# Mean value theorem sum of $\frac{1}{f ' (x _k)}$

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be a function which is derivable in $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.

Show that for every $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$, there exists numbers $x_1,x_2,.....,x_n$ all in $[0,1]$ such as
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{f'(x_k)}=n
\end{equation}

I think the mean value theorem should be applied:
\begin{equation}
\exists\; x_1 \in (0,1): f'(x_1)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\exists\; x_2 \in (0,x_1): f'(x_2)=\frac{f(x_1)-f(0)}{x_1-0}=\frac{f(x_1)}{x_1}
\end{equation}
etc.

We have the sum 
\begin{equation}
1+ \frac{x_1}{f(x_1)} + \frac{x_2}{f(x_2)} +....+\frac{x_{n-1}}{f'(x_{n-1})}
\end{equation}
But than I get stuck.
I was wondering if anyone could be so kind to help

Thanks in advance for your time and assistence

Comment: As you've noticed, there's a $y \in [0,1]$ such that $f ^ \prime (y) = 1$. Why not thaking $x_1 = x_2 = \dots x_n = y$?

Comment: "... differentiable in $[a,b]$ ..." What are $a$ and $b$?